# Triggering a click() event in a timeout function

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

My user interface has a dual-use button that should open a small color palette when clicked, or a full RGB color selector (an HTML5 color input element) when held down for 500ms.

The implementation for such a button is straightforward: The mousedown event sets a timer that triggers fnHold when it expires; the mouseup event clears the timer and triggers fnClick if the fnHold hasn't been triggered yet; the mouseleave event clears the timer and does nothing.

My example code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/vwoof2a5/1/ (in this example, the button should do the same thing when it is clicked or held down).

```
  var mouseHold = function(element, duration, fnHold, fnClick) {
    var timeout = 0;
    var held = false;
    fnHold = fnHold.bind(element);
    fnClick = fnClick.bind(element);

    element.on({
      mousedown: function() {
        timeout = setTimeout(function() {
          held = true;
          fnHold();
        }, duration);
      },
      mouseup: function() {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        if (!held) fnClick();
        held = false;
      },
      mouseleave: function() {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        held = false;
      }
    });
  };


$(document).ready(function() {
  mouseHold($('#holder'), 500, function() {
    $('#log').append("<p>Hold event</p>");
    $('#color').click();
  }, function() {
    $('#log').append("<p>Click event</p>");
    $('#color').click();
  });
});
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work in all browsers. <del>Chromium has no problem, but</del> Firefox doesn't open the color selector when the button is held. It *does* run the timer function, but the $('#color').click() just doesn't go through.

I'm not sure if this is a security feature (not allowing timer functions to trigger a click) or something other problem, and I don't know how to work around it. Is there another way to open the selector that doesn't depend on click()?

The timer could be avoided entirely by comparing times on mouseUp, but that forces users to decide how long to hold down the button, and is less convenient.

Edit: Chromium doesn't do it either; the earlier result might have been a fluke.

Edit2: Chromium's reaction is confusing. As pointed out by James Montagne, the hold-event does *not* work the first time after the page has loaded or the first time after the regular click has been tested, but works normally thereafter.

Comment: I'm running Firefox 34 and the color palette opened.

Comment: In chrome it seems hold works as long as it isn't preceded by a click.  Also doesn't work the first time.

Comment: I should add that this worked (seemingly) in Firefox 34 when I first coded it early in January, but I recently discovered it had stopped working. It's possible this was broken in Firefox 35 or 36.

Comment: Seems to me like it's a browser 'bug' that assumes that only one element can be clicked at same time. By that I mean that you won't be able to click another element than $('holder') until its click-event is propagated in ff 35&36. I came to this conclusion since jsfiddle.net/vwoof2a5/11 works for me where the fnHold function is triggered when the button is released... Anyway this solution is not satisfying :(

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert on Events, but you may have more luck using $(selector).trigger('click') to trigger the click and $(selector).on('click') to define the handler.

I generally use all jQuery or all raw JS so that these issues don't happen.

I am interested if these work.